# mobile web, radio buttons vs select/option

Tags: html, mobile, input

A bit of a random questions but here goes.

I am re-developing a website to be mobile friendly and it has a massive form with lots of `<input />` tags.  as I Was researching similar sites and there solutions I found that `<select><option>...` are a bit intrusive and radio buttons worked better for me.

As this will go in a report I don't think saying "the best input method is radio buttons as I like then" will cut it somehow.  does anyone have any good suggestions on what is the "best" way?  OR is there a way of getting a vote going?

any help or direction is (as always) appreciated

Update: As I think of it, smart phones convert a drop-down list into a set of radio buttons and shows the user that in a similar popup/dialog box to the keyboard.  is this a good excuse? hehe :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a UI/UX consideration, plus you have to take into consideration if more select/radio options will be added in the future.

If there are more than 3 or 4 selections I would make those elements selects from a UI/UX standpoint.

Mobile browsers have no problem displaying any sized select, there are some jQuery plugins that you can find that will offer alternative interactions.

If more select/radio options are going to be added down the road (from a database for example) then radio buttons won't be a good choice.  Nothing like trying to select from 15 radio buttons.

In the end I prefer to let the browser take control of the select and display it to its default setting.  Trying to style over or replace a select with a third party solution can get a bit sticky when going cross browser.

Hope this helps to answer your question.

Comment: thanks for the quick response its helping to confirm my original thought (not posed here, opps). I also followed you all the way up to "In the end I prefer to .... going cross browser."  I was not planning on disabling/overriding the phones default action is that what you where getting at here?.
also I will hold of ratting for now as I would like to see what else pops up but it will get something in a week or so :-)

Comment: There are overlay solutions out there to override select elements in the dom (for example, dropkick, etc).  I tend to stay away from these unless the design of the website calls for over styled selects.  Most of the time overlay solutions work but I have had issues with them in more complex, heavy data sites.